# Cannot find module '@middy/core' when running jest with typescript and esm

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, middy

hello I am running typescript with esm and jest and I have a problem with middy:

I had this test:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { lambda } from '../index.js';

describe('get-by-id handler', () => {
  test('Should not find id', async () => {
    const x = jest.fn();
    x();
    expect(x).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

which worked fine with the configurations I supplied below and `npm run test` command.
howerver when I changed it to look like this:

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, Context } from 'aws-lambda';
import { lambda } from '../index.js';

describe('get-by-id handler', () => {
  test('Should not find id', async () => {
    const res = await lambda({
    pathParameters: { id: 'id' },
    } as unknown as APIGatewayEvent, {} as Context);
    console.log(res);

    const x = jest.fn();
    x();
    expect(x).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I get this error

```
jest -c jest.config.cjs

FAIL  app/src/handlers/get-by-id/tests/index.test.ts
● Test suite failed to run

    app/src/handlers/get-by-id/index.ts:4:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@middy/core' or its corresponding type declarations.
    
    4 import middy from '@middy/core';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.409 s, estimated 13 s
Ran all test suites.
```

here is the config:
`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "./node_modules/@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
}
```

`jest.config.cjs`:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(ts?)$',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
    },
};
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run copy-files && npm run tsc",
    "copy-files": "copyfiles -e \"!{*.md,package?(-lock).json}\" \"**/*.*\" dist",
    "clean": "rimraf ./dist",
    "tsc": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json",
    "deploy": "cdktf deploy",
    "lint": "npx eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx",
    "test": "jest -c jest.config.cjs",
    "coverage": "jest -c jest-cov.config.cjs"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cdktf/provider-aws": "^18.0.6",
    "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.2",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.129",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.10",
    "@types/node": "^20.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.13.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.13.0",
    "cdktf": "^0.19.1",
    "constructs": "^10.3.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8.54.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.0",
    "eslint-plugin-require-extensions": "^0.1.3",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.460.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.460.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb": "^3.460.0",
    "@middy/core": "^5.0.3",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1"
  }
}
```

handler:

```
import type { APIGatewayEvent } from 'aws-lambda';
import middy from '@middy/core';
const handler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent) => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
    };
};

// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const lambda = middy().handler(handler);
```

running on node `20.9.0`

what I have tried so far step by step:

1. changing `test` script in `packge.json` to this
   `"NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest -c jest.config.cjs"`
   as mentioned [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules)
   result was the same
2. changing `jest.config.cjs` to this:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(ts?)$',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
    },
    transform: {
        // '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts with `ts-jest`
        // '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts/mjs/mts with `ts-jest`
        '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
            'ts-jest',
            {
                useESM: true,
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

as mentioned [here](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support#use-esm-presets)
result was the same

3. changing `jest.config.cjs` to this:

```
const esModules = ["@middy"].join("|")
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(ts?)$',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
    },
    transform: {
        '^.+\.ts?$': [
            'ts-jest',
            {
                useESM: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
};
```

as mentioned [here](https://middy.js.org/docs/intro/testing/#jest-and-typescript)
result was the same

4. changing `tsconfig.json` to this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "module": "es2020",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "composite": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "tests/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://middy.js.org/docs/intro/typescript)
got this error:

```
ReferenceError: jest is not defined

       9 |         console.log(res);
      10 |
    > 11 |         const x = jest.fn();
         |                   ^
      12 |         x();
      13 |         expect(x).toHaveBeenCalled();
      14 |     });

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/src/handlers/get-by-id/tests/index.test.ts:11:19)
```

Comment: Interesting. I face the exact same problem right now. Since there is not much information available about this issue, maybe this issue was introduced with an update of some dependency?

Comment: I am having a similar issue. From the google'ing I've done, it _seems_ that esm can't be used with jest. Please please please tell me I'm wrong and also please please please tell me you've found an answer. The maintainer just pointed me to https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c and it does not seem like a quick fix.